# Unable to hide the panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-2.0, buttonclick

I am making an asp.net Web Forms Application. If any user gives wrong input, then it shows validation. But, the second time when the user gives correct input, the code works properly, only problem is the error message does not get removed.


In the Page Load Function

```
pnlStatus.Visible = true;
```

The Button_Click Event is written Below

```
 protected void btnAffRntGoClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dtFrom = new DateTime();
    DateTime dtTo = new DateTime();
    bool dt1 = true;
    bool dt2 = true;
    int result;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, out dtFrom) == false)
    {
        dtFrom = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        dt1 = false;
    }

    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtEndDate.Text, out dtTo) == false)
    {
        dtTo = new DateTime(2100, 1, 1);
        dt2 = false;
    }
    result = DateTime.Compare(dtTo, dtFrom);
    if ((dt1 == true && dt2 == true) && result > 0)
    {
        lblPageStatus.Text = string.Empty;
        pnlStatus.Visible = false;


        DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString(), "SPNAME",
        Convert.ToInt64(ddl.SelectedValue), dtFrom.Date.ToShortDateString(), dtTo.Date.ToShortDateString(), ddl2.SelectedValue, Chk1.Checked);

        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
// Code to generate Excel
        }
        else
        {
            pnlStatus.Visible = true;
            lblPageStatus.Text = "No data available to export.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        pnlStatus.Visible = true;
        lblPageStatus.Text = "Please Check the Dates";
    }
}
```

Anytype of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you changing the required values in the if statement that generates excel?

Comment: certainly your code needs to be code reviewed

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer is** I guess you only need to update your controls accordingly when there is data.

```
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
       // Code to generate Excel
        pnlStatus.Visible = false;
        lblPageStatus.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        pnlStatus.Visible = true;
        lblPageStatus.Text = "No data available to export.";
    }
```

---

**Long answer** - your code should be cleaned and alligned with some standards to achieve readibility. Probably this is the reason you got lost. Additional methods could be introduced for simplifying. Below is quick overview. Additionally `pnlStatus.Visible` and `lblPageStatus.Text` could be set in one place with single line of code(but a bit more complicated readibility).

Things to consider:

- Give meaningfull names to your variables
- Avoid code duplication(follow [DRY,KISS,YAGNI](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/what-are-dry-kiss-solid-etc-classified-as); use [extension methods](https://www.dotnetperls.com/extension))
- Make your code as much readable as it is possible(means anyone could read your code)

  ```
  private const string connectionString = 
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

  protected void btnAffRntGoClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      var from = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
      var to = new DateTime(2100, 1, 1);

      var isValidStartDate = !DateTime.TryParse(txtStartDate.Text, out from);
      var isValidEndDate = !DateTime.TryParse(txtEndDate.Text, out to);

      var hasValidDates = isValidStartDate && isValidEndDate;
      var hasDifference = DateTime.Compare(from, to) > 0;

      var shouldCheckDates = !hasValidDates || !hasDifference;

      if (shouldCheckDates)
      {
          pnlStatus.Visible = true;
          lblPageStatus.Text = "Please Check the Dates";
          return;
      }

      DataSet ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(connectionString,
          "SPNAME",
          Convert.ToInt64(ddl.SelectedValue)
          , @from.Date.ToShortDateString(),
          to.Date.ToShortDateString()
          , ddl2.SelectedValue
          , Chk1.Checked
      );

      var hasData = ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0;

      pnlStatus.Visible = !hasData;
      lblPageStatus.Text = hasData ? string.Empty : "No data available to export.";

  }
  ```